# rails on ruby, how to make low bandwidth version of app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, web-deployment

I want temporarily save my data from datebase to local while my client login to my website app, and he can process all his order in a offline mode. he need internet only when he's done with order and send. How can i get this?

Comment: with javascript and local storage in a modern browser

Comment: but local storage is based on JS, means it's in the View, not in the controller

Comment: The Rails end should consist of an API (for instance a JSON-API) the client is talking to. The rest happens on the client and is therefore part of the assets. You might want to choose a JS framework in case there's some heavy lifting required on the client side.

Comment: offline stuff means client side...

Comment: Html5 has WebSQL, anyone tried it before? like Html5 WebSQL+ ruby on rails = offline app